# Why are some of Persian characters removed while cleaning the URL?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Here is the function I use to make the URLs clean:

```
function make_clean_url($url){

    $url_word_separator = "-";

    // To replace new lines with space
    $url = preg_replace('/\n+/', " ", $url);

    // To replace spaces with -
    $url = preg_replace('/\s+/', "-", $url);

    // To replace dot(s) with -
    $url = preg_replace('/\.+/', "-", $url);

    // To remove html-entitis characters i.e &laquo;
    $url = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i","",$url);

    // To remove eveything except numbers, dash, number-sign, space and alphabet characters
    $url = preg_replace('/[^\x{600}-\x{6FF}a-zA-Z0-9 #\-]/u', '', $url); -- issue on this

    // To trim surrounded spaces and dashs
    $url = trim($url, " $url_word_separator");

    return $url;
}
```

This regex works for the most of URLs as well. Juse there is an exception:

```
echo make_clean_url("اﺻﻠﯽ ﺗﺮﯾﻦ ﻓﺮق اﺳﺘﻌﺎره ﻣﺼﺮﺣﻪ و ﻣﮑﻨﯿﻪ ﭼﯿﺴﺖ؟");
//=> ا--ق-اره--و--؟
```

#### [Demo](https://3v4l.org/OGM15)

See? It has removed the most of alphabet characters. Why? Those characters are in Persian which is allowed by `\x{600}-\x{6FF}`. So why they are removed?

Comment: https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%D8%A7%EF%BA%BB%EF%BB%A0%EF%AF%BD%20%EF%BA%97%EF%BA%AE%EF%AF%BE%EF%BB%A6%20%EF%BB%93%EF%BA%AE%D9%82%20%D8%A7%EF%BA%B3%EF%BA%98%EF%BB%8C%EF%BA%8E%D8%B1%D9%87%20%EF%BB%A3%EF%BA%BC%EF%BA%AE%EF%BA%A3%EF%BB%AA%20%D9%88%20%EF%BB%A3%EF%AE%91%EF%BB%A8%EF%AF%BF%EF%BB%AA%20%EF%AD%BC%EF%AF%BF%EF%BA%B4%EF%BA%96%D8%9F

Comment: In `/[^\x{600}-\x{6FF}a-zA-Z0-9 #\-]/u`, `a-zA-Z`  only supports ASCII letters. Try `/[^\x{600}-\x{6FF}\p{L}0-9 #-]+/u`

Answer (score 1):

Those characters that are being removed are outside of `\u0600-\u06ff`, so the behavior is expected. Those are rare forms of Persian letters e.g. `ﭼ` is not the same as `چ`.

You probably need to include Arabic script using `\p{Arabic}` instead of `\x{0600}-\x{06ff}`. This would be the whole function:

```
function make_clean_url($url) {
    $url_word_separator = '-';
    $url = preg_replace('/\R+/', ' ', $url);
    $url = preg_replace('/[\s.]+/', '-', $url);
    $url = preg_replace('/&#?[a-z0-9]+;|[^\p{Arabic}a-z0-9#-]+/ui', '', $url);
    $url = trim($url, " $url_word_separator");
    return $url;
}
```

See [live demo here](https://3v4l.org/hiASJ)